# Go through an array starting with different positions

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to go through an array:

```
public static String calculate(int [] bills,int amount){
int size = bills.length;        
int cache = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cache+=bills[i];
    if(cache==amount){
        return "OK";
    }
}
return "NO OK";
}
```

that would go through the array(and sum) in this order:

1 2 5 7 = 1,3,8,15  (sums)

But What I would like is this:

1st iteration: 1 2 5 7 = 1,3,8,15

2nd iteration: 2 5 7 1 = 2,7,14,15

3rd iteration: 5 7 1 2 = 5,12,13,15

4th iteration: 7 1 2 5 = 7,8,10,15

Note: I'm calling 1st,2nd,3rd,4th since I'm referring to the case of 2 loops;
and technically what I want to do is that from the 2nd iteration and so on when it reaches index[3] it goes then to index[0] and and add them up. then start from index[2] and when getting index[3] it sums index[0] and [1].

I tried it on different ways using a double for(and j=i) and when the j(of the 2nd for)
reached to last postion of array ([3] in this case) change it to zero and the size=i(which would be the point it started) but it didn't work properly... 
also maybe it could work with (% modulus) but I would like to see other people's ideas which always helps on learning :) thanks guys!

PS: I used this one as array(ignore the amount part of the method since is not part of the question):

```
int[] bills = new int[] {1,2,5,7};
```

PSS: This is the code I tried (with the double loops and it wasn't the one with less mistakes I made because I missed it since I deleted and changed a lot trying new things and this one might have horrible mistakes..):

```
    public static String calculate(int [] bills,int amount){

    int size = bills.length;        
    int cache = 0;
    int c = 1;
    int z = size-1;
    int s = 0;
    int w = 0;
    boolean TIME = false;

        for (int i = w; i < size;) {

            for (int j = i; j < size;j++){ 
                cache+=bills[j];
                if(cache==amount){
                    cache=0;
                    return "OK";
                }
                System.out.println(TIME);
                if(i>0 && j==z && TIME){
                    size=i;
                    i=0;
                    TIME=false;
                }
            }
            w++;
            size=z+1;
            cache=0;
            TIME=true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why does it matter what order you add the numbers up in?

Comment: Please show what you "tried" and how it  differed from what you want.

Comment: done, thanks. I wanted to try some possibilites without using recurrency on this array of 4 ints, kkind of brute force tho... I have the other tries or sums which this way doesn't give but this one was the only remaining to make it works. Thanks for helping and thanks asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple logic that does that. You can add a new array and then as you loop through your bills array, you can add the sum of the index plus previous one to the new array, print the array and then re-order the numbers of the bills array and repeat the loop.

You can use the [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) to change the order of elements in your bills array. Let's assume you have

```
bills > [2, 5, 7, 1] : sum > [2, 7, 14, 15]
```

Now you need to rotate your bills array, so the follow does so using arrayCopy

```
int firstElement = bills[0];
System.arraycopy(bills, 1, bills, 0, size-1);
bills[size-1] = firstElement;
```

Above three lines, copy the first element of array, then use arrayCopy to copy `bills[1]`, `bills[2]`, `bills[3]` to the same array in position `bills[0]`, `bills[1]`, `bills[2]` respectively (basically remove backing up first element and then shifting all elements to the left) an the finally copying the first element at the end of array with `bills[size-1] = firstElement`. For more details on how arrayCopy works see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm) and javadoc link is given above.

You will get the following:

```
[2, 5, 7, 1] : [2, 7, 14, 15]
[5, 7, 1, 2] : [5, 12, 13, 15]
[7, 1, 2, 5] : [7, 8, 10, 15]
[1, 2, 5, 7] : [1, 3, 8, 15]
```

Here is the code sample,

import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class SumArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] bills = new int[] { 2, 5, 7, 1 };
        int size = bills.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int[] sum = new int[size];
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    sum[j] = bills[j];
                } else {
                    sum[j] += sum[j - 1] + bills[j];
                }
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bills) + " : " + Arrays.toString(sum));

            int firstElement = bills[0];
            System.arraycopy(bills, 1, bills, 0, size-1);
            bills[size-1] = firstElement;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the question was about.

Comment: thanks, I'd rather use this one for getting the series but just as Scott said the question was about how I could go trhough that array(4 times) adding them up and first starting at 0 normally, then going through the array but starting at index[1] and when it reached [3] continue to 0. and so on :)

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you for pointing out, I missed a section of the question. I updated my answer to at least give the series.

Comment: thanks man! this worked very well;), I'll research about the syntax of arraycopy deeper ;) I will test Scott's also.. upvote!

Comment: @NormanCarrizo not sure if you can upvote yet due to low reputation, anyway you are welcome, glad the answer was of some help after all. Thanks to Scott for flagging the issue with initial answer.

Comment: @Raf a last question man: I didn't get very well those numbers on the arraycopy method would you explain me?thanks a lot!

Comment: Haha sure, basically the first argument to the arrayCopy is the source array, second argument is starting index of source array (that's why I put 1 so I skip first element), third argument is destination array (which I choose same array), and fourth arg is starting index of destination array (0 here because, i want to shift elements to left and add the first element to the vacated space at the end), and finally 5th argument is the number of elements to be copied. See here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `start` is the index of the item you wish to start with, this should do the trick:

```
cache += bills[(i+start)%size];
```

Comment: Yes, just double iterate start and i from 0 to bills.length

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Scott Hunter's answer. Try

```
for (int start = 0; start < size; start++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cache += bills[start + i];
        if (cache == amount) {
            // You probably want to keep track of indices added to cache...
            return "OK";
        } else if (cache > amount) {
            cache = 0;
            // this break breaks out of the "i" loop, but continues the "start" loop
            break;
        }
    }
}
return "NO OK";
```