# Write a method that rotates a one-dimensional array with one position to the right in such a way that the last element becomes the first element.

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

I think I confused the methods and can't get the actual methods correct. Please help, the array needs to rotate to the right where the first digit will become the last digit. I generate a random array based on size that the user input. Then I print that array, then do the rotation, then print the new array with the first digit last and the last digit first.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class modOne {

   public static final int MIN = 1;
   public static final int MAX = 15;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int arraySize = 0;

     System.out.println("How many arrays to rotate right?");
     int howMany = input.nextInt();

     while(howMany <= 0) {
       System.out.println("ERROR! Should be positive. REENTER: ");
       howMany = input.nextInt();
     }

     while(howMany > 0) {
       System.out.println("Enter array size: ");
       arraySize = input.nextInt();
     }

     int[] a = new int[arraySize];
     int[] b = new int[arraySize];

     getRand(a, MIN, MAX);
     System.out.println("The array before rotation: ");
     printArray(a);
     System.out.println("THe array after rotation: ");
     transArray(a);
     printArray(b);


     System.out.println("Enter array size: ");
     arraySize = input.nextInt();
   }

   public static void getRand (int[] list, int size, int low, int up) {

     Random rand = new Random();
     for(int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
       list[r] = rand.nextInt(up - low + 1) + low;
     }
   }

   public static void printArray(int[] list, int size) {
     for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
       System.out.printf("%5d", list[r]); 
       if(r % 6 == 5)
         System.out.println(); 
     }
     System.out.println(); 
    }

   public static void transArray(int[] list, int size) {
     for(int r = 0; r < size - 1; r++) {
       list[r] = list[r-1];
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: What you need? {1,2,3,4,5,6} become {6,1,2,3,4,5} or {6,5,4,3,2,1}?

Comment: @antonu17 I need this:

The array before rotation: 
8 15 2 10 11 15 1 3 
The array after rotation: 
3 8 15 2 10 11 15 1

Comment: It's rotating to the right and the last digit becomes the first.

Comment: Why use a whole loop to just change position of one element?

Comment: So yes, like your first example.

Comment: you can use System.arrayCopy to do that

Comment: How would I do that in terms of writing a new method?

Comment: @ArthurLukyanovskiy see my answer, I have provided the same input and output that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) to copy sourceArray from start index to destination array from start index. You can also specify how many elements should e copied as last argument to [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) method. See below:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{8, 15, 2,10, 11,15,1,3}; 

System.out.println("array before rotation: " + Arrays.toString(arr));

int lastElement = arr[arr.length -1 ];
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, arr.length-1);
arr[0] = lastElement;

System.out.println("array after rotation: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

I backup the last element and then copy the array entirely in a new array skipping the first element of the array and then I assign the first element of the array with the value that I backup early.

The output you get is as follow:

```
array before rotation: [8, 15, 2, 10, 11, 15, 1, 3]
array after rotation: [3, 8, 15, 2, 10, 11, 15, 1]
```

For more details on how System.arrayCopy works, you can see the following [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm) or read my answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988570/go-through-an-array-starting-with-different-positions/33988661#33988661).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < validData.length / 2; i++)
{
    int temp = validData[i];
    validData[i] = validData[validData.length - i - 1];
    validData[validData.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

The logic behind this is that you are swapping the values until you get to the center:

**I made this image for you to better understand**
[image]

Here, there is no center, but if there was a `3.5`, then it would ignore the three point five because `validData[validData.length - i - 1] = temp;`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to invert the order and save the value you are going to overwrite to recover it later. I also took the liberty to make some other changes to your code. Now it should work as intended.

```
    while (howMany <= 0) {
        System.out.println("ERROR! Should be positive. REENTER: ");
        howMany = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Enter array size: ");
    arraySize = input.nextInt();

    int[] a = new int[arraySize];
    int[] b = new int[arraySize];

    getRand(a, MIN, MAX);
    System.out.println("The array before rotation: ");
    printArray(a);
    System.out.println("THe array after rotation: ");
    printArray(transArray(a));

}

public static void getRand(int[] list, int low, int up) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int r = 0; r < list.length; r++) {
        list[r] = rand.nextInt(up - low + 1) + low;
    }
}

public static void printArray(int[] list) {
    for (int r = 0; r < list.length; r++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d", list[r]);
        if (r % 6 == 5) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static int[] transArray(int[] list) {

    int temp1 = list[list.length - 1];

    for (int r = list.length - 1; r >  0; r--) {
        list[r] = list[r-1];
    }

    list[0] = temp1;

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `Arrays.copyOfRange(T[] original, int from, int to)` in order to shift most of the array. Some numbers are cut off, though, and need to be placed back in afterwards.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    arr = rot(arr, -1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
}


public static int[] rot( int[] arr, int amt ) {
    while ( amt < 0 )
        amt += arr.length;
    amt = amt % arr.length;
    int[] k = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, amt, arr.length + amt);
    for ( int i = 0; i < amt; i++ )
        k[k.length - amt + i] = arr[i];
    return k;
}
```

`rot()` rotates left by `amt`, so using the parameter amt = -1 achieves what you set out to do.

The `rot()` method first forces `0 ≤ amt < arr.length`. This is because once you rotate by the full length of the array, you're back where you started. Next it shifts the array by amt, adding the integer's default value (0) to the end as padding to preserve length. Finally, it adds the lost elements back into the array where the 0's were placed.